# Vuex: Access object by key

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex

I have state with

```js
bs: {
  page: 1,
  posts: {}
}
```

Here, I'm storing data with mutation of

```js
state.bs.posts[Number(state.bs.page)] = posts // => posts array is coming from an http request
```

Edit: Here I've tried by converting it to String(state.bs.page) as well but Not getting desired output

so whenever I'm trying to access with a getter, for example

```js
getBSPosts (state) {
    return (pageNo) => {
      return state.bs.posts[Number(pageNo)]
    }
}
```

Now, the getBSPosts returns undefined in component/page wherever I'm trying to get.
It's returning `__ob__` observer how do I get value of key named `1` (which is page no as key in posts object)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript objects with numeric keys can be accessed with either a number or a string, so you don't need to concern yourself with type casting the keys.

The issue is that the property isn't being reactively set due to Vue's [Object reactivity caveat](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects).  It's necessary to use [`Vue.set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) when creating object properties on a reactive object:

Import `Vue` into the store:

*store.js*

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
```

And use `Vue.set` to set the object data:

```js
Vue.set(state.bs.posts, state.bs.page, posts);  // ✅ Correct
```

```js
state.bs.posts[Number(state.bs.page)] = posts;  // ❌ Incorrect
```

Comment: It's probably not applicable for nuxt.js

Comment: Also the incorrect way which you pointed, even official docs says that i should assign with `=` https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#commit-with-payload

Comment: The example you linked shows setting a primitive on `state`, *not* setting an object property.  Vue has a reactivity caveat when setting object properties. This is the doc you should be looking at:  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects

Comment: It's just as required with Nuxt.  Without it, your new properties won't be immediately reactive